# google's many of pages, on every refresh html element class is different, why?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, security

Tried to inspect a page in google console and found that on every refresh,
the class name of element changes and this name is random.

I want to know the exact reason for this and.

1. is it possible to achieve this through javascript so as to avoid resource consumption overhead.
2. if this is to be achieved from server side, is it worth considering the resource consumption overhead?

Example would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the class is generated server-side, it's probably on page load. This would mean that js would generate a random sequence for an element, and the selector would also be changed. This would mean that the styles are written inside the HTML file, inline or inside a style tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is called css modules.
A hash of the classname is generated either at server runtime or during compilation. Most of the time it is done during the build/compilation phase.
Then served to you as hashed css classnames.
Most of the time it is achieved using javascript and webpack (compiler)

Both options have no overhead to the client.

Done only to avoid clashes in css names and breaking layout.